# MSSQL says I am trying to convert a varchar to a string when I'm not

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

So I have this fairly long procedure at Work that I just made. What it does it not that important, but the end result is what matters.

I need to count some different types of descriptions in a table and that Works fine. I then need to take the two things that I Count and put them in a string that I return to my software. However, every time I run this procedure it gives me this:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure WorkDays, Line 43 Conversion
>   failed when converting the varchar value
>   'FlightDeck:161,CabinCrew:189' to data type int.

I just can't figure out why it keeps telling me this when I am not trying to convert a varchar to an int but rather ints to a single varchar.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WorkDays] @requestedDate nchar(10)

AS
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
DECLARE @date as nchar(10) = ''
DECLARE @returnVal as varchar(30) = ''
DECLARE @flightDeck as int = 0
DECLARE @cabinCrew as int = 0
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @date = @requestedDate

SELECT
    @flightDeck = SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.Crew_Category.Description LIKE 'Flight Deck' THEN 1 END),
    @cabinCrew = SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.Crew_Category.Description LIKE 'Cabin Crew' THEN 1 END)
FROM
    dbo.CrewMember INNER JOIN
    dbo.Crew_Category ON dbo.CrewMember.CrewCategorySeqNo = dbo.Crew_Category.CrewCategorySeqno
WHERE        
    (dbo.Crew_Category.Description = N'Flight Deck' OR
    dbo.Crew_Category.Description = N'Cabin Crew') AND
    (dbo.CrewMember.EmploymentEndDate > @date)
    AND dbo.CrewMember.CrewSeqno NOT IN (
        SELECT
            CrewMember_1.CrewSeqno
        FROM 
            dbo.CrewMember AS CrewMember_1 INNER JOIN
            dbo.CrewReqAsg ON CrewMember_1.CrewSeqno = dbo.CrewReqAsg.crewSeqno INNER JOIN
            dbo.activity ON dbo.CrewReqAsg.act_seqno = dbo.activity.act_seqno INNER JOIN
            dbo.ActivityType ON dbo.activity.actType_seqno = dbo.ActivityType.actType_seqno INNER JOIN
            dbo.ActivityCategory ON dbo.ActivityType.ActCat_seqno = dbo.ActivityCategory.actCat_seqno INNER JOIN
            dbo.Crew_Category AS Crew_Category_1 ON CrewMember_1.CrewCategorySeqNo = Crew_Category_1.CrewCategorySeqno
        WHERE (
            dbo.ActivityCategory.Category = N'Ferie' OR
            dbo.ActivityCategory.Category = N'Fridage' OR
            dbo.ActivityCategory.Category = N'Sygdom') AND (Crew_Category_1.Description = N'Flight Deck' OR
            Crew_Category_1.Description = N'Cabin Crew') AND (LEFT(dbo.activity.Start,10) LIKE @date));
            SET @returnVal = 'FlightDeck:'+CAST(@flightDeck AS varchar);
            SET @returnVal += ',CabinCrew:'+CAST(@cabinCrew AS varchar);
END
RETURN @returnVal
```

It's been a while since I've had to do this so perhaps I just forgot something fundamental. Please help me figure out why this happens? :)

Comment: explicit conversion how can varchar can converted into integer

Comment: Have you located line 43?

Comment: @jarlh Yes it is the very last line "RETURN @returnVal"

Comment: Have you tried to google for RETURN? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174998.aspx. Return can only return INTs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you forgot something fundamental. To return data to the caller, use SELECT, not RETURN.

You need

```
SELECT @returnVal
```